# Trouble with inserting decimal numbers to ms-acces with JDBC

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, decimal, sql-insert

When I use prepared-statement my numbers get rounded off to integers as they are inserted into ms-access.
I extract my numbers from a worksheet and java prints them on my screen correctly (system.out.println).

I've tested different field properties such as number with standard format, big numbers etc. The ms-access table shows my numbers with 2 decimals but it seems that at some point during transfer to ms-access my numbers are rounded off.

```
while(from < to) {
   String sheetname =  methods.get(i).getSheet();
   String sample = ws.getRow(from).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
   double cs = 
   ws.getRow(from).getCell(methods.get(i).getCol()).getNumericCellValue();
   double ls = ws.getRow(from).getCell(4).getNumericCellValue();
   String assays = ws.getRow(from).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
   double SN = ws.getRow(from).getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();

   PreparedStatement stmt; stmt = c.prepareStatement("insert into " + table + 
   " (" + columns + ")" + " values(?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 

   stmt.setString(3,sheetname);
   stmt.setString(4, sample);
   stmt.setDouble(6, cs);
   stmt.setDouble(1, ls);
   stmt.setString(2,  assays);
   stmt.setDouble(5, SN);
   stmt.executeUpdate(); 
   from = from + 1; 
}
```

My expected results are numbers containing decimals, for example 25,2 are inserted into ms-access as 25,00. No error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the error to be due to formatting. Java writes separators with dot whilst my access wants the separators to be comma. Now as Java always wants your formatting with a dot you cannot format it with comma and still keep it as a double. Therefore the solution for me is to change the column property to String and later when I extract values convert them to double in java.
Here is a link to the whole ms access problem:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/01d1da4d-4294-44f3-976a-2aa771fa4a03/bug-in-ms-access-decimal-numbers-separator?forum=accessdev